# JSON to JSON transformation library for .net

Tags: .net, json

What are the options to have JSON transformation in .net;

Currently I have resorted to JUST https://github.com/WorkMaze/JUST.net however this does not seem to have active contribution.

JSON transformation example needed: 
From

```
{
"root": [{
        "question": 1,
        "answer": "ans"
    },
    {
        "question": 2,
        "answer": [{
                "a": 0
            },
            {
                "b": 0
            },
            {
                "c": 1
            },
            {
                "d": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "question": 3,
        "answer": {
            "text": "verbose"
        }
    }
]
}
```

To

```
{"1":"ans", "2":["c", "d"], "3":{"text":"verbose"}}
```

Comment: are transformation dynamic, or always work in a similar way

Comment: btw could you perhaps convert the example to use actual json format, as it is hard to figure out

Comment: Transformation are dynamic. They'll be configured at runtime.